# match "[" with ruby regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to match a string that includes the characters 0-9.-,[], something like this:

```
return true if str =~ /\A[0-9.-,\[\]]*\Z/
```

Which works except it doesn't seem to match the braces, how do I match those?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to escape the `.` and `-` characters:

```
str =~ /\A[0-9\.\-,\[\]]*\Z/
```

Comment: This will also match an empty string. Change `*` to `+` to make sure the string has at least one character in the set.

Comment: "." is not special inside [brackets].

Answer (score 3):

turns out it also works w/o escaping the . and - characters like this:

```
str =~ /\A[\[\]0-9.,-]*\Z/
```

Comment: Inside a set using square brackets, dot (.) is no longer special. However, dash (-) is unless it is the last character in the set.